# Unable to use swiper effect on these elements. Horizontal allignment question

Tags: html, css, html-lists, swiper.js

I have ul of li elements. This ul is wrapped in 2 divs, parent div has flex display, because I want to set these product elements in horizontal order. Other div also wraps all li elements. But then on the 2nd and 3rd element I need to wrap them in an extra div, EXCLUDING the first element, which is just a li element, otherwise it doesn’t work. This is a mystery.
Please analyse my code and explain why I need to wrap 2nd and 3rd element in an extra div, but not the first one.
Also, how would you go about implementing swiper effect in such a setting? I tried using swiper js library and ot does nothing.
HTML(EJS)

```
<div class="swiper-section">
    
    <div class = "swiper">
    
    
    
    
    <ul class="product-grid">
        
        
        
        
        <li class="product-card">
            <div class="product-item">
      <img src="<%= dhea.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= dhea.title %>" class = "product-image"/>
      <div class="product-item-content">
        <h2 class = "product-title"><%= dhea.title %></h2>
        <div class="product-item-actions">
            <% if (locals.isAdmin) { %>
                <a class="btn" href="/admin/products/<%= dhea.id %>">View and Edit</a>
                <div class="divider">
                    <button
                    class="btn btn-alt"
                    data-productid="<%=dhea.id %>"
                    data-csrf="<%=locals.csrfToken %>"
                    >
                    Delete
            </button>
            <% } else { %>
                <a class= "btn btn-alt" href="/products/<%= dhea.id %>">View Details</a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>


<div class = "wrapper">

<li class = "product-card" id = "mid">
    <div class="product-item">
       <img src="<%= fivehtp.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= fivehtp.title %>" class = "product-image"/>
       <div class="product-item-content">
          <h2 class = "product-title"><%= fivehtp.title %></h2>
      <div class="product-item-actions">
         <% if (locals.isAdmin) { %>
          <a class="btn" href="/admin/products/<%= fivehtp.id %>">View and Edit</a>
          <div class="divider">
             <button
             class="btn btn-alt"
             data-productid="<%=fivehtp.id %>"
             data-csrf="<%=locals.csrfToken %>"
             >
             Delete
          </button>
          <% } else { %>
             <a class= "btn btn-alt" href="/products/<%= fivehtp.id %>">View Details</a>
             <% } %>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</li>



<li class = "product-card" id = "last">
    <div class="product-item">
       <img src="<%= melatonin.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= melatonin.title %>" class = "product-image"/>
       <div class="product-item-content">
          <h2 class = "product-title"><%= melatonin.title %></h2>
      <div class="product-item-actions">
         <% if (locals.isAdmin) { %>
          <a class="btn" href="/admin/products/<%= melatonin.id %>">View and Edit</a>
          <div class="divider">
             <button
             class="btn btn-alt"
             data-productid="<%=melatonin.id %>"
             data-csrf="<%=locals.csrfToken %>"
             >
             Delete
          </button>
          <% } else { %>
             <a class= "btn btn-alt" href="/products/<%= melatonin.id %>">View Details</a>
             <% } %>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</li>

</div>

</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:var(--body-font)

}


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,200&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');

html {
   /*Colors*/
  
    --color-gray-50: rgb(226, 223, 223);
    --color-gray-100: rgb(133, 133, 133);
    --color-gray-300: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    --color-gray-400: rgb(59, 59, 59);
    --color-gray-500:rgb(46, 44, 44);
    --color-gray-600:rgb(43, 41, 41);
    --color-gray-700:rgb(34, 33, 33);

    --color-primary-50: rgb(248, 255, 187);
    --color-primary-100: rgb(139, 201, 226);
    --color-primary-200:rgb(114, 203, 241);
    --color-primary-300:rgb(37, 76, 128);
    --color-primary-400:rgb(51, 37, 100);
    --color-primary-contrast:rgb(122, 202, 212);
    --color-primary-200-contrast:rgb(62, 106, 187);

    --color-white:rgb(245, 245, 245);

    --color-error:rgb(214, 34, 34);
    --color-error-600:rgb(119, 1, 1);

    --color-primary-bg:rgb(51, 134, 167);

 /*Font and typography===*/
    --header-font: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
    --header-font-big:'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    --body-font-main: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    --body-font-special:'Nunito', sans-serif;


    --large-font-size:1.85rem;
    --medium-font-size:1.50rem;
    --smaller-font-size:1.25rem;
    --small-font-size:1rem;

    --space-1: 0.15rem;
    --space-2:0.25rem;
    --space-3: 0.8rem;
    --space-4:1rem;
    --space-6:1.5rem;
    --space-8:2rem;

    --border-radius-small:4px;
    --border-radius-medium:6px;

    --shadow-medium: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}



h1 {
    margin-left:10rem;
    margin-top:3rem;
    font-size:3rem;
}
h2 {
   top:0;
    margin-left:11rem;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
    color:var(--color-primary-200);
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:var(--header-font);
}
#h2-img {
    position:absolute;
    top:48rem;
 
}
.section {
    padding:2rem;
    margin-left:5.5rem;

   
}
.main-img {
margin-top: 2rem;
    width:50vw;
    margin-right: 8rem;
margin-bottom: 6rem;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    shape-outside: circle();
}
.article {

    font-family:var(--body-font);
    font-weight:var(--small-font-size);
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}


.text {
    font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
}
p {
   

}

#trending {
    margin-right: 10rem;
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}



.product-card {
    height:100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
width:14rem;
background-color: var(--color-primary-200-contrast);
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
height:21rem;
margin-bottom:2rem;
}

#mid {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;


}

#last {
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
 


}

.product-item {
 
margin-top:1rem;
height:19rem;
    width:12rem;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-medium);
    text-align:center;
    background-color: var(--color-gray-50);
    overflow:hidden;

}

.product-item img {
    padding:2px;
    background: var(--color-primary-200);
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    width:11rem;
    height:13.5rem;
    object-fit:cover;
   border:2px solid var(--color-primary-200-contrast);

    border-radius: var(--border-radius-medium);
}

.product-item-content  {

    padding:var(--space-2);
}

.product-item-content  h2{

    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin:var(--space-1) 0;
}
.product-title {
  top:0;
    font-family: var(--header-font-big);
    font-size: var(--header-font);
    color:var(--color-gray-700);
}
.product-item-actions {
    display:flex;
    gap:var(--space-4);
    margin-top:var(--space-2);
    justify-content: center;

}

.product-item-actions .btn {
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    height:1.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    padding:0 var(--space-2);
    font-size: 13px;
    justify-content:space-between;
    font-family: var(--body-font-special);
    font-weight:bold;
    color:var(--color-primary-400);
    border: 2px solid var(--color-primary-200-contrast);
    background-color: var(--color-primary-contrast);
    opacity: 60%;
   
}

.product-item-actions .btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-primary-50);
    opacity:70%;
    color: var(--color-gray-700);
}

.product-item-actions .btn btn-alt {
margin-left: 10px;
}





.swiper-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

I added additional div to wrap the second and third element. That allowed me to allign elements horizontally. However, now the issue is that I can't use grid on my ul element, since the div is blocking the access to list elements. So I'm stuck. I want to implement swiper effect.